# How can I temporarily send SMS text messages instead of iMessages to a specific contact using Messages on Mac?

Tags: mac, catalina, messages, sms

I have a contact that I text with regularly on my Mac with the Messages app (version 13.0). Usually we use iMessage. But they don't have an iPhone, so if they send me an SMS message, I know they're on their phone. It shows up in the same conversion. By default, it has me reply by iMessage, which they wouldn't get immediately because they're not on their Mac. I used to be able to simply pull down a menu from the contact, and switch to their phone number to send as an SMS instead. But at some point in the past (probably a macOS update), that option disappeared. Instead, I have to start a new conversion, start typing their name, and then I can select their phone number to send as SMS. Once I select that, it immediately merges into the previous conversion (though it still has me sending as SMS). Is there an easier way to accomplish this? It seems like a ridiculous amount of effort for such a common task.

Comment: I believe the way you are doing it is the only way. The only other suggestion that I can think of, is to have their SMS/iMessage accounts as two separate contacts say "John Smith iMessage" and "John Smith SMS". This way you can quickly go to a specific conversation in iMessages or SMS, but you won't have them showing up as one continuous conversation between the two contacts.

Comment: @AVelj Thanks, it's a bit awkward but on net definitely an improvement.